# TitlePageIndicator can not be resolved to a type in android

Tags: java, android, rss, feed

Hi i have to develop android BBc news reader application from [BBC news reader application](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader)

Here i have to import these app from above link and run the app means i get the following error.how can i resolve these error ??? please help me

The error is :

TitlePageIndicator cannot be resolved to a type...i got the error on below line...

```
TitlePageIndicator pagerIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.categoryPagerIndicator);
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?

Comment: i got the below error on my problems tab:http://pastie.org/private/opkzowl8qr5ivoasj57q     no error is display on my console window.

Comment: I will need more code than that to help you out.

Comment: You should not ask one question and then in an hour change it and ask other question! First question was about RssFeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should read project [README](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader#references)**

We use several other projects to help us:

- android-rss - a lightweight rss library - https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss
- ActionBarSherlock (v4.1.0) - ui compatibility for <4.0 devices - http://actionbarsherlock.com
- ViewPagerIndicator (v2.4.1) - page indicator in the category view - http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference
- drag-sort-listview (v0.4.1) - allows sorting of categories when choosing - https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/
- Eula - displays the "eula" at first run - 
  http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/DivideAndConquer/src/com/google/android/divideandconquer/Eula.java

TitlePageIndicator  is a part of ViewPagerIndicator, RSSFeed is a part of android-rss and so on.
Just download this libraries, build it and add to your project.

Comment: yes i have added all library files....am getting below error while run the program...please check it and give me solution for these..:http://pastie.org/private/mt6lyqnwypqa2qkbpycwa

how can i clear these error ???

Comment: Do you create dialog or something else? You need to dismiss it before exiting from activity. In any case this information not enough, try to create new question and provide more logs and code.